# Logstash command not found

Tags: kibana

After installation I make config file in `/etc/logstash/logstash.conf` and try to run `logstash` command.

When I run following command

> root@ip:~# logstash --version

always showing error:
showing command not found.

Answer (score 13):

In this case do following thing:

Search the location of **logstash** using following command

```
root@whereis:~# whereis logstash
```

output:

```
logstash: /etc/logstash /usr/share/logstash
```

then goto

```
root@whereis:~# cd /usr/share/logstash
root@ip:/usr/share/logstash# cd bin
root@ip:/usr/share/logstash/bin#
```

Run command from here like:

```
root@ip:/usr/share/logstash/bin# logstash --version
```

If you still not able to run and getting error command not found then the current directory isn't listed in your path. If you want to run a program in the current directory you can use like `./program_name`:

```
root@ip:~# ./logstash --version
```